# fail to flush the buffer in fluentd to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

Describe the bug

logs are not getting transferred to elasticsearch.

Expected behavior

logs from the source folder should've been transferred to elasticsearch.

Your Environment

Fluentd or td-agent version: td-agent 1.11.2

Operating system: Linux

Your Configuration

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/smtp-api/storage/logs/fluentd/*
  pos_file /home/smtp-api/storage/logs/fluentd/access-logs.pos
  tag smtp.access
  format json
  read_from_head true
</source>

<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/smtp-api-2/storage/logs/fluentd/*
  pos_file /home/smtp-api-2/storage/logs/fluentd/access-logs.pos
  tag smtp.access2
  format json
  read_from_head true
</source>

<match smtp.*>
  @type elasticsearch
  host elk-data.amartya-int.int
  <buffer>
    @type file
    path /var/log/fluent/smtp
    compress gzip
  </buffer>
  port 9200
  logstash_format true
  logstash_prefix smtp.access
</match>
```

Your Error Log

```
2021-05-17 15:30:41 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=3 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 15:30:45 864793371479422728793/2199023255552000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 15:30:41 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-05-17 15:30:46 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=4 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 15:30:53 1246145672473190896169/2199023255552000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 15:30:46 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-05-17 15:30:53 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=5 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 15:31:09 431493802875340255437/549755813888000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 15:30:53 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-05-17 15:31:10 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=6 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 15:31:44 36018824927254535859/274877906944000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 15:31:10 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-05-17 15:31:45 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=7 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 15:32:41 213226392719973317877/274877906944000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 15:31:45 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-05-17 15:32:41 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=8 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 15:34:46 14488516743329774951/68719476736000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 15:32:41 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
^[2021-05-17 15:34:46 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=9 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 15:38:59 1590472627730823409/17179869184000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 15:34:46 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-05-17 15:38:59 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=10 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 15:48:09 6447852607269569521/8589934592000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 15:38:59 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-05-17 15:48:10 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=11 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 16:05:21 2422140701418556159/8589934592000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 15:48:10 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-05-17 16:05:21 +0530 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=12 next_retry_seconds=2021-05-17 16:43:30 22032519751758471/268435456000000000 +0530 chunk="5c279c260c779ea13a39e5ac45c9b1a9" error_class=IOError error="closed stream"
  2021-05-17 16:05:21 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
```